# How to install openERP 7.0.1 on centOS 6.5

Tags: odoo, centos6

Can you please give me the steps of how to install openERP 7.0.1 version in my centOS 6.5 version. I was searching for this for quit a while but dint find anything. Can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Modified script from Carlos E. Fonseca Zorrilla 
# http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic36094.html
yum -y install wget unzip
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh http://yum.pgrpms.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-6-i386/pgdg-centos92-9.2-6.noarch.rpm
yum -y install python-psycopg2 python-lxml PyXML python-setuptools libxslt-python pytz \
            python-matplotlib python-babel python-mako python-dateutil python-psycopg2 \
            pychart pydot python-reportlab python-devel python-imaging python-vobject \
            hippo-canvas-python mx python-gdata python-ldap python-openid \
            python-werkzeug python-vatnumber pygtk2 glade3 pydot python-dateutil \
            python-matplotlib pygtk2 glade3 pydot python-dateutil python-matplotlib \
            python python-devel python-psutil python-docutils make\
            automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel byacc flashplugin-nonfree poppler-utils pywebdav\
yum -y install postgresql92-libs postgresql92-server postgresql92
service postgresql-9.2 initdb
chkconfig postgresql-9.2 on
service postgresql-9.2 start
su - postgres -c "createuser  --superuser openerp"
cd /tmp
wget http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/files/gdata-2.0.17.zip
unzip gdata-2.0.17.zip
rm -rf gdata-2.0.17.zip
cd gdata*
python setup.py install
cd /tmp
adduser openerp
DIR="/var/run/openerp /var/log/openerp"
for NAME in $DIR
do
if [ ! -d $NAME ]; then
   mkdir $NAME
   chown openerp.openerp $NAME
fi
done
rm -rf openerp*
wget http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/src/openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz  --transform 's!^[^/]\+\($\|/\)!openerp\1!'
cd openerp
python setup.py install
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/openerp-server
cp openerp-server /usr/local/bin
cp install/openerp-server.init /etc/init.d/openerp
cp install/openerp-server.conf /etc
chown openerp:openerp /etc/openerp-server.conf
chmod u+x /etc/init.d/openerp
chkconfig openerp on
service  openerp start
```

Comment: Code only, no explanation?

Answer (score 0):

it's almost same as Ubuntu here you can follow these steps

Install and configure the database server, `PostgreSQL`

```
sudo yum install postgresql
```

Then configure the `OpenERP` user on postgres:

First change to the postgres user so we have the necessary privileges to configure the database.

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Now create a new database user. This is so `OpenERP` has access rights to connect to `PostgreSQL` and to create and drop databases. Remember what your choice of password is here; you will need it later on:

```
createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --pwprompt openerp Enter password for new role: * Enter it again: *
```

Finally exit from the postgres user account:

```
exit
```

Install the necessary Python libraries for the server

```
sudo yum install python-dateutil python-docutils python-feedparser python-gdata \ python-jinja2 python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-mock python-openid \ python-psycopg2 python-psutil python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing \ python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-unittest2 python-vatnumber python-vobject \ python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi
```

and you can also use pip and easy_install to install python packages

Download Openerp Server

and extract the file than run the `openerp-server`